# Cypress: How to get <li> only without its children <li>?

Tags: cypress

I'm recently using cypress and I want to get the array of list but I just want the to get  `<li>` under the class "list" and not including the other children of `<li>`

I'm using

```
cy.get('.list >li')
```

but I'm also getting the children `<li>` under Home.

```
<ul class="list">
 <li>Home</li>
   <ul>
     <li>Another One</li>
     <li>Another Two</li>
   </ul>
 <li>Page</li>
 <li>Hello</li>
 <li>Hi</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your HTML markup is incorrect, you can only have `<li>` elements as child of `<ul>`. The browser wraps your `<ul>` in a `<li>` to make it valid, so you also get the nested ul in your query. Correct your HTML to solve this.

Comment: This is exactly where i am testing. I am getting {"Home Another One Another two","Page", "Hello","Hi"} what i want to get is {"Home","Page", "Hello","Hi"}

Comment: Instead of posting the same comment everywhere please read what I wrote and fix the issue, you have invalid code.

Answer (score 4):

you have two ways to do this

1. get only li children of parent

   `cy.get('.list').children('li')`
2. get children by level in dom

   ```
   cy.get('.list > li')
     .its('length')
     .should('eq', 2)
   ```

Comment: Thank you! didn't know about .children before now i need to read some of the documentation first

Comment: Option 1 work for me initially but digging deeper on my code i'm getting {"Home Another One Another two","Page", "Hello","Hi"} instead {"Home","Page", "Hello","Hi"}

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the combination of selector and text using `contains`. In this way you will only get the intended `li` element.

```js
cy.contains('li', 'Home')
```

You can do something like this as well:

```js
cy.get('ul.list > li').each(($ele) => {
  cy.log($ele.text()) //prints Home Page Hello Hi
})
```

Created a small POC from your HTML and this is what I got:

[image: POC Screenshot]

Comment: The text may be changed so contains text is not a option for me on this one

Comment: I follow your solution and I don't know why i'm getting {"Home Another One Another Two","Page", "Hello","Hi"} instead of {"Home","Page", "Hello","Hi"}

Comment: Then your html structure is different. Because as per the HTML you added in the question, this should work.